# Why Domains in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf does not take effect?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I need to add a new DNS search domain. Currently the "search" field in /etc/resolv.conf is like:

```
search mshome.net
```

I need to add "mine.net" in front of "mshome.net". What I did was directly editing the file and changed to:

```
search mine.net mshome.net
```

It worked. But there are some comment in the file saying this file is generated, I figure there are better ways. I checked [resolved.conf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolved.conf.5.html) man page, it has this -

```
   Domains=
       A space-separated list of domains optionally prefixed with
       "~", used for two distinct purposes described below. Defaults
       to the empty list.

       Any domains not prefixed with "~" are used as search suffixes
       when resolving single-label hostnames (domain names which
       contain no dot), in order to qualify them into
       fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs). These "search domains"
       are strictly processed in the order they are specified in,
       until the name with the suffix appended is found. For
       compatibility reasons, if this setting is not specified, the
       search domains listed in /etc/resolv.conf with the search
       keyword are used instead, if that file exists and any domains
       are configured in it.
```

I edited file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and added mine.net:

```
Domains=mine.net mshome.net
```

After the editing, I ran this:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

But it did not work.

Do you see what I missed?